# Using laptop (without os) as an external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I want to use my laptop as an external hard drive. I've deleted all partitions and run `shred` so the hdd is completely empty. There is absolutely nothing on it.

Is it possible to connect the laptop to an other computer such that the hard drive can be used as an external hdd? Maybe by formatting the hdd with FAT/FAT32?

I don't want to remove the hdd.

Comment: How did you plan to access to it? USB, ethernet, ... ? By lan you can think to install a tiny linux with samba and network drivers...

Comment: @Hastur: LAN cable? Or wouldn't that work without an os? Actually I don't care how I access it as long Windows 10 will recognize it.

Comment: @Hastur: So without installing anything on the laptop it won't work?

Comment: Usually no, (but with a [mac](http://www.howtogeek.com/214322/how-to-boot-your-mac-in-target-disk-mode-for-easy-file-transfers/) ). BTW, if you can, I suggest you to put the HDD it in an external case... or to connect with a dockstation or a _flying cable_... Else it's a waste of space and energy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by making clear, that the by far fastest, easiest and most reliable way to achieve this is to take a 5$ USB case, put the laptop's hard drive into it and forget about the (now diskless) laptop.

If you do insist on going the hard way (and assuming the laptop has soem LAN connection) the most promising way is to set aside a small partition on the harddisk, install one of the easier Linux distributions on it (I recommend Ubuntu) and then use tools such as LIO or IETD to create an iSCSI target on the rest of the harddisk. You can then use any iSCSI initiator (including the Windows bulit-in) to connect to it and use it as a hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

If the old laptop is a mac, you can boot it in target diskmode by holding down the T key while it boots. You can then connect to it via Firewire or Thunderbolt.

If not you will need an OS on it. That can be some free software (e.g. [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/)) and then you can connect to it via the network.

Alternatively, just remove the disk from the laptop and put it in an external drive case.